# why Python list() does not always have the same order?

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.5 and the documentation for it at 
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range
says:

```
list([iterable])
```

(...)

```
The constructor builds a list whose items are the same and in the same order as iterable’s items.
```

OK, for the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import random

def rand6():
    return random.randrange(63) 


random.seed(0)
check_dict = {}

check_dict[rand6()] = 1
check_dict[rand6()] = 1
check_dict[rand6()] = 1

print(list(check_dict))
```

I always get

```
[24, 48, 54]
```

But, if I change the function to:

```
def rand6():
    return bytes([random.randrange(63)])
```

then the order returned is not always the same:

```
>./foobar.py
[b'\x18', b'6', b'0']
>./foobar.py
[b'6', b'0', b'\x18']
```

Why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157819/discussion-on-question-by-mark-galeck-why-python-list-does-not-always-have-the).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python dictionaries are implemented as hash tables. In most Python versions (more on this later), the order you get the keys when you iterate over a dictionary is the arbitrary order of the values in the table, which has only very little to do with the order in which they were added (when hash collisions occur, the order of insertions can matter a little bit). This order is implementation dependent. The Python language does not offer any guarantee about the order other than that it will remain the same for several iterations over a dictionary if no keys are added or removed in between.

For your dictionary with integer keys, the hash table doesn't do anything fancy. Integers hash to themselves (except `-1`), so with the same numbers getting put in the dict, you get a consistent order in the hash table.

For the dictionary with `bytes` keys however, you're seeing different behavior due to Hash Randomization. To prevent a kind of dictionary collision attack (where a webapp implemented in Python could be DoSed by sending it data with thousands of keys that hash to the same value leading to lots of collisions and very bad (`O(N**2)`) performance), Python picks a random seed every time it starts up and uses it to randomize the hash function for Unicode and byte strings as well as `datetime` types.

You can disable the hash randomization by setting the environment variable `PYTHONHASHSEED` to `0` (or you can pick your own seed by setting it to any positive integer up to `2**32-1`).

It's worth noting that this behavior has changed in Python 3.6. Hash randomization still happens, but a dictionary's iteration order is no longer based on the hash values of the keys. While the official language policy is still that the order is arbitrary, the implementation of `dict` in CPython now preserves the order that its values were added. You shouldn't rely upon this behavior when using regular `dict`s yet, as it's possible (though it appears unlikely at this point) that the developers will decide it was a mistake and change the implementation again. If you want to guarantee that iteration occurs in a specific order, use the `collections.OrderedDict` class instead of a normal `dict`.